# Magento Product pages calling wrong category url

Tags: php, error, 404

I am creating a new template theme for my magento store, I am using an old version of magento so I thought I would upgrade to the new version.

I am creating it on a new store in a subdirectory but it seems sooo slow compared to the current version of magento. I am still using all the same themes & extensions.

I have run a webpage speed test and it is saying when on a product page (http://www.hjtemplate.hjjewellery.co.uk/category-1/product-1.html) it is also trying to load this URL (http://www.hjtemplate.hjjewellery.co.uk/category-1/)

The only problem is.. that isn't my category URL, my category URLs end with .html so it is returning a 404 error. Any ideas why this is happening and what can I do to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you see what is trying to load this page? It sounds a bit odd.

Answer (score 2):

The url your product page is loading is loaded by your CloudZoom module (javascript).
On line 173 of cloud-zoom.1.0.2.js you have this line :

```
$mouseTrap = jWin.parent().append(format("<div class='mousetrap' style='background-image:url(\".\");z-index:999;position:absolute;width:%0px;height:%1px;left:%2px;top:%3px;\'></div>", sImg.outerWidth(), sImg.outerHeight(), 0, 0)).find(':last');
```

The part `background-image:url(\".\")` is loading an image from the parent path so `http://www.hjtemplate.hjjewellery.co.uk/category-1/`

Try it using your browser to see by yourself (Chrome helps a lot tracing javascript errors in the console).

Maybe your module misses some config for that background-image.
Find out what it is doing on that line, and what is supposed to replace the path in the background-image directive.

Comment: Nice one! just removed the background-image. thanks